# using kotlin how can I append array to a 2d array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I want to take coordinates and add them to an array that i want to return from a function but i don't know how to append in kotlin to an empty array with another array

```
 var temp:Array<Array<Int>> = arrayOf<Array<Int>>()
                var i:Int = 0
                while (true){
                    // if you see another of the same type then break
                    if(currentPlayer == 1){
                        if(ystart-i < 0){ // if you would go out of bounds on the next it and the current one does not have an opposite then breakwith temp as nothing
                            temp = arrayOf<Array<Int>>()
                            break
                        }else if(touchnum[ystart-i][xstart] == 1){
                            break
                        }else{
                            val slice: IntArray = intArrayOf(xstart, ystart-i)
                            temp.plusElement(slice)

                        }

                    }else{

                    }
```

Comment: Use MutableList. Array is for when you want the number of elements to never change.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are of fixed length on the JVM. Once created, you can't change their length.
The equivalent concept for dynamically growing arrays is called a list.

In Kotlin, they are represented by the [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/#kotlin.collections.MutableList) interface (or `List` when you need a read-only reference).
You can create an instance of `MutableList` with the function `mutableListOf<T>()` (where `T` is the type of the elements in the list). Then you add elements using `list.add(element)`.

That was for your "main" list. Now let's talk about the elements you put in it.

In Kotlin it is not very idiomatic to represent tuples (like coordinates) as arrays. For 2D coordinates, there is already a type called [Pair<A, B>](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/). But honestly it's so cheap to write a domain-specific class yourself that I encourage you to create your own, such as:

```kotlin
data class Point2D(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

And then you can add instances of this class to your list:

```kotlin
list.add(Point2D(xstart, ystart-i))
```